# Unable to delete a large extended partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, diskpart

I am trying to delete the extended partition 0 because it occupies a lot of space in my disk. I deleted all swap partition and tired again to delete it but it always shows the same error message:

**Virtual Disk Service error:
The extended partition is not empty.**

How can I deletet this partition using diskpart?

```
C:\windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: YUSUF-ST

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB    11 GB

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             58 GB  1024 KB
  Partition 0    Extended           112 GB    58 GB
  Partition 5    Logical            100 GB    58 GB
  Partition 2    Primary             48 GB   170 GB
  Partition 3    Primary            167 GB   219 GB

DISKPART> select partition 0

Partition 0 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> detail partition

Partition 0
Type  : 05
Hidden: No
Active: No
Offset in Bytes: 62916656128

There is no volume associated with this partition.

DISKPART> delete partition

Virtual Disk Service error:
The extended partition is not empty.
```

Comment: You could try [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/) to fix this.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this using diskpart? and what is the reason of this error?

Comment: You have one choice: wiping all your computer up and repartition your hard drive, at that point you can create 4 primary and no logical partition . This should be your last option.
Also I have a question: Does windows have swap? as I saw swap is for unix based os not windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partition 0 basically reserves disk space for a limited number of sub-partitions.

In what you are showing Partition 5 is contained totally within Partition 0.

Thus you cannot delete partition 0 without FIRST deleting Partition 5.

This means that the error message is entirely correct.

Answer (score 1):

An extended partition is a container for logical partitions.  Without this kind of partition, you would be limited to 4 partitions per hard drive,

The extended partition 0 contains partition 5, for example.