# (Windows 10 + GParted) How do I rearrange disk partitions to I can merge free space to my main partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, clone, gparted, clonezilla

I had a 120 GB SSD with my OS, some software, and some files. I used Clonezilla to make a proportional clone on a 1 TB SSD. Now, the 1 TB SSD shows the following partitions:

System Reserved: 500 MB

SSD (C:): 694.54 GB

Recovery Partition: 3.86 GB

Free Space: 232.61 GB

Unallocated:  22 MB

[image]

I want to allocate the Free Space and Unallocated space to the Main Partition (C:), but since they're non-adjacent I can't. I'd love to reorder the partitions, perhaps placing the Recovery partition before the Primary? I've done a lot of research but can't seem to find an answer that works. I have a GParted Live USB that I'm using for the solution but if there's a better tool for the job please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to move the recovery partition on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1453790/how-to-move-the-recovery-partition-on-windows-10) ?

Comment: @DocBrown Theoretically, yes, it does answer my question, but I'm afraid this is quite a bit over my head. I would prefer a solution that uses GParted Live or some other graphical tool because I'm scared this will end poorly for me.