# Consequences of a screwed up recovery environment?

Tags: windows, partitioning

So I recently upgraded a machine to Windows 11 and for some reason, the partitions got messed up. I managed to follow a tutorial and used diskpart to convert a normal partition into a recovery partition:

```
select disk 1
select partition 4
set id="ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7"
gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001
```

I tried following many online tutorials including this one [How to move the recovery partition on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1453790/how-to-move-the-recovery-partition-on-windows-10) but to no avail, when I run `reagentc /info`, it outputs

```
Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) and system reset configuration
Information:

    Windows RE status:         Enabled
    Windows RE location:       \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk1\partition3\Recovery\WindowsRE
    Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 85502705-3ba1-11ee-a674-2cf05d9e7cb3
    Recovery image location:
    Recovery image index:      0
    Custom image location:
    Custom image index:        0

REAGENTC.EXE: Operation Successful.
```

Now notice that the Windows RE location is in partition 3 which is my main C: drive. However, in disk management, I see this:
[image]
Keep in mind, the highlighted partition is actually partition 4, but no matter how hard I try, the command above still points to partition 3. I am now wondering if there are any consequences to accidentally booting into recovery mode? Since it thinks its in partition 3, would booting into recovery mode or using recovery tools nuke my main operating system? Or would it be smart and use that partition 4 dedicated to a recovery partition? Even though these questions are doomsday scenarios, I really do not want to find out and accidentally nuke my important files just because I used recovery settings.

Comment: No I do not have dual boot, Windows 11 is installed normally it seems to me and I can use it fine.

Comment: Yeah I was just going to wing it but I was wondering if my installation ever got corrupted, what would happen? Should I not go into recovery mode? Because I am afraid recovery mode will overwrite my C: partition with its stuff which deletes all my stuff on C: drive.

Comment: I suggest that using the computer when the disk is this screwed-up is asking for trouble. Better to take backup of your files, format the disk and reinstall Windows and apps.

Comment: 1. Full disk images are far more effective than Windows Recovery. Make (and verify!) images periodically, create a USB rescue environment, and you have lost nothing without Windows Recovery. After all, should there be serious drive issues, the Recovery partition could be damaged. 2. If you do want to reinstall that partition, as others have mentioned, do a full install from ISO --and if that wipes the disk, then restore Windows from the  image.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik can you tell me more about full disk recoveries? Will it restore my windows state like a virtual machine snapshot?

Comment: A full disk image is a snapshot of **everything** on the SSD or HDD. If the drive goes bad, and you replace it and restore from the image, you'd be back at the same state as when the image was made.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Recovery does not immediately nuke anything. It boots into a WinPE image, then you get a bunch of menus where you can choose what you want to do (ranging from a full reimage to just opening a Cmd console).

Comment: It *might* be necessary to let installation wipe the disk and do a full reinstall to get back the Recovery partition.