# How to install windows 11 without recovery partition blocking the way

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-installation, partition-recovery

I wanna fresh install windows 11 and then dualboot it with linux, but when i install windows 11 there's recovery partition automaticaly created and blocking the way of extending volume for linux.

How can i fresh install windows 11 without recovery partition or make recovery inside the main windows partition or just simply make it on the left side of the main windows partition?

Answer (score 1):

1. How much drive space do you have? Many Linux installers, such as Ubuntu, will install perfectly well even though Windows installation creates *multiple* partitions: ESP (EFI), Recovery, System, etc.

   In the screenshot below,the first five partitions (0-4) include boot files, OEM restoration riles, recovery data and the ~500 GB Windows OS partition. The last two (5 & 6) were created by Ubuntu installation. Note that I shrunk the Windows partition to leave space for Linux.

[image: Windows & Linux Partitions]

After about 8 years, less than a third of the Ubuntu partition is used, i.e., it's using only 60 GB (you mileage may vary). If *your* drive has at least 50 GB free near the end, installation should proceed without issue. *If you do not* have enough free space, don't install a second OS.

2. If you have space, but the file system needs to be moved around,

   - Use a tool such as diskmgmt.msc or [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) to shrink the C: partition. The partition cannot easily be shrunk beyond the location of system files, and the tool should show that.
   - It is possible [to move the Recovery Partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1453790/how-to-move-the-recovery-partition-on-windows-10), but *not* simple.

**N.B.** *Any operation that modifies disk layout is inherently risky*.

```
After Windows installation, make a full drive image before changing drive layout.
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue, first backup all your data before making any changes. Now you can go for a clean installation of Windows 11 which will delete all your data and install a fresh window without any data, or you can reinstall the windows without losing data which will involve a few steps.

**Install a Clean Windows 11**:

•   Download Windows 11 from Microsoft’s website

•   Download the Media Creation tool from Microsoft’s website.

•   Run the medicreationtool.exe and choose the language & edition you want.

•   Insert a bootable USB for Windows installation of 8GB or more. Select the “USB Flash Drive” option and let it write Windows 11

•   Restart your computer and boot from the USB drive, if required change the boot order in your BIOS settings to prioritize the USB drive.

•   Follow the on-screen instructions to begin the Windows 11 installation.

•   When you reach the partitioning stage, choose “Custom Installation” to manually configure your disk partition.

•   Delete all existing partitions on your hard drive. This includes the recovery partition.

•   After deleting the partitions, create a new partition for Windows 11. You can allocate the entire space to this partition if you don’t want a separate recovery partition.

•   Follow the remaining steps of installation, once done your system will reboot into Windows 11.

•   After installing Windows 11, you can proceed to install Linux, during installation, you can choose to install it alongside Windows. The installer will automatically detect the Windows partition and set up the dual boot configuration.

**Reinstall Windows 11 Without Losing Data**:

o Open Settings.

o Click on System.

o Click on Recovery on the right side.

o Under the “Recovery options” section, in the “Reset this PC” setting, click the “Reset PC” button to begin Windows 11 reinstallation.

o Select the “Keep my files” option.

o Choose the “Cloud download” option to download Windows 11 for a fresh reinstallation.